# Determining ONVIF Protocol S support

Tags: camera, protocols, onvif

Is there a way to determine whether Profile S is supported by looking at the ONVIF responses/profiles in the device?  Do I just assume if the profile includes Video Source configuration, that Profile S is supported?

Answer (score 3):

As you can read in section 9 of the [ONVIF_Profile_-S_Specification_v1-1-1](https://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/ONVIF_Profile_-S_Specification_v1-1-1.pdf),

> A device compliant to this specification shall additionally include
>   the specific scope parameter as presented in Table 1: Scope
>   parameters. Apart from this pre-defined parameter, it shall be
>   possible to set any scope parameter as defined by the device owner.
>   Scope parameters can be listed and set through the commands provided
>   by the Device service, defined in the ONVIF Core Specification.
>
> ```
> +--------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
> |Category|Defined values|Description                                              |
> +--------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
> |Profile |Streaming     |The  Streaming  scope  indicates  if  the  device  is    |
> |        |              |compliant to the Profile S. A device compliant to the    |
> |        |              |Profile S shall include a scope entry with this value in |
> |        |              |its scope list.                                          |
> +--------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
> ```

So, in order to know if the device claims Profile S support, you need to check if the scope `onvif://www.onvif.org/Profile/Streaming` is present.

Comment: @LittleGreenViper /10/media and /20/media are services (you get them with GetServices), while Streaming is a scope (you get it with with GetScopes)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a onvif Media client with:
https://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl

This client can request the supported profiles with 'GetProfiles'.